# Remove quantizationParameters in arcgis javascript api 4.26 featurelayer retrieval

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am trying to remove the quantizationParameters in arcgis javascript api 4.26 featurelayer retrieval:

This worked for ArcGIS javascript api 3.x but no longer works: (quantize: "false")

```
// Creating layer
var myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://...",
    quantize: "false",
...
```

The get request (fetching the featurelayer from server) still contains the quantizationParameters even with above property (quantize: "false") added:

**GET**

```
...&quantizationParameters={"extent":{"spatialReference":{"wkid"....
```

The quantize: "false" flag no longer removes the quantizationParameters.  Any help on how to remove this parameter would be appreciated.